# How to get the total revenue of my account in stripe (Node.js)?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I need to get the total revenue of my account as daily,weekly,monthly,yearly from stripe payment gateway . Is there any way to do it in Node.js API ?

I tried this one ,

```
var stripe = require("stripe")(
  "sk_test_R8lnqjR3wPDwbMhsc2pti0yN"
);

 stripe.balance.retrieve(function(err, balance) {
  console.log(balance);
 });
```

But this will return available amount only . I need as daily,weekly,monthly,yearly wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the stripe api for retrieving [all transactions](https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#balance_history) and then you can compute your result per month day etc...

```
var stripe = require("stripe")(
  "sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2"
);

stripe.balance.listTransactions(
  {
    starting_after: startAt, //specify your start date
    ending_before: endAt, // specify your end date
  }, function(err, transactions) {

    // here sum the balance for the transactions
});
```

Comment: This solution will likely require pagination. Rather use the payouts as this will likely not. Also starting_after and ending_before are used as cursor locations, not date ranges

Comment: I was looking for a solution to this same problem in 2023 and there still doesn't seem to be simple way to retrieve it via a single API call w/o computing it from a transaction history like described in this answer, which seems to be the right way. I'm using Stripe connect and when I view the connected account in the Stripe Dashboard I can see the stat I believe I'm looking for as "Lifetime total volume" but searching through the API docs didn't yield any other solutions other than those presented.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution to get your net profit is to use the [payouts](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payouts/list?lang=node#list_payouts-arrival_date) instead of the balance data. This will probably save you from having to manage pagination as you will likely not have more than 100 payouts if you just want the past 30 days of revenue for example.

Here what my code looks like.

```
const payouts = await stripe.payouts.list({
  created: { gte: ..startRangeTimestamp.., lte: ..endRangeTimestamp.. } as any,
  limit: 100 // Maximum limit (10 is default)
});

const amountTotal = payouts.data.reduce((a: any, b: any) => ({ amount: a.amount + b.amount })).amount;
```

Comment: Note, if you haven't paid out anything for the month, this will return 0. Even if you have made money that month.